# Implementing classification tree with lists and vectors

Tags: r, data-structures, classification

So, I'm playing around with R in order to get the hang of Classification Trees. I'm primarily interested in making a abstract data type for the the Classification Tree so I can start building it. But unlike, C, Java, etc I can't have pointers to other nodes. I'm limited to lists and vectors.

How can I build this? Any tips?

Comment: Lists can contain other lists and can thus be used to implement recursive data structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By playing a little bit with `data.tree` in R, I constructed this

```
library(data.tree)
my.tree <- Node$new('my tree')
my.tree$key <- 1
my.tree$var.name <- 'blahblah'

function <- insert.Node(tree=NULL, key=1, var.name='abcd'){

    if (is.null(tree$key)){
        # Creation of root
        tree = Node$new(paste(var.name, " < ", key, sep = ''))
        tree$key <- key
    } else if (key < tree$key) {
        # Left child
        tree$AddChildNode(insert.Node(tree$children[[1]], key, var.name))
    } else {
        # Right child
        tree$AddChildNode(insert.Node(tree$children[[2]], key, var.name))
    }

}


tree <- insert.Node(tree=my.tree, key = 4, var.name = 'hello world')
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: That's actually a bit simpler than lists and vectors :P